# Using sed "s| ACT: ||"

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am begineers to linux. Though I have gone through the different syntax of **sed** command , but still do not able to understand this form:

```
sed "s|key:  ||"
```

Please someone help me in understanding this form sed, here key could be any word.
I am confused, how it is replacing here `key` to something or not?

Comment: `|` is perfectly valid here, although `/` is more commonly used. Often `|` will be used if the pattern contains `/` to avoid escaping it and making the expression hard to read.

Comment: @FatalError I had no idea. That is sneaky. Will remove my comment. Perhaps that's where OP is tripping up as well; where `s/key:  //` is synonymous with `s|key: ||`.

Comment: It's replacing the string `key:  ` with the empty string, i.e., removing it. What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: From `info sed`: *The syntax of the 's' (as in substitute) command is
's/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/FLAGS'.  The '/' characters may be uniformly
replaced by any other single character within any given 's' command.
The '/' character (or whatever other character is used in its stead) can
appear in the REGEXP or REPLACEMENT only if it is preceded by a '\'
character.*

Comment: Well all be damned @Cyrus Thank you for sharing that. `echo "foo key:  bar" | sed "sgkey:  gg"` that is crazy and I can't believe I haven't run into that yet.

Comment: @BenjaminW., I was confused `key` is replaced by what, if you are saying it is replacing with empty string, then might this is the answer.

Comment: @Arya Are you familiar with `s/key://` synthax?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I am familar with sed syntax like sed  "s/key1/key2"

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou But saw the first time like this `sed "s|key:  ||"`

Comment: @Arya In the familiar syntax `s/key1/key2/` , `key2` can be an empty string, which will actually lead to deletion of `key1` : replace `key1` with one empty string => delete `key1`. Keys in sed can be separated by `/` or by any other character like `|`

Answer (score 2):

Here's `info sed`:

> The 's' command (as in substitute) is probably the most important in
>   'sed' and has a lot of different options.  The syntax of the 's' command
>   is 's/REGEXP/REPLACEMENT/FLAGS'.
>
> **The '/' characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single
>   character within any given 's' command**.  The '/' character (or whatever
>   other character is used in its stead) can appear in the REGEXP or
>   REPLACEMENT only if it is preceded by a '\' character.

This means that you can use `s/foo/bar/g`, `s|foo|bar|g`, `s#foo#bar#g`, `skfookbarkg` or any other character, and it all means the same thing. `/` is merely conventional.

(Fun fact: this means that some English words like `streetlight`, `serenade` and `synonymously` and are valid sed `s` commands.)

Comment: To add (as I think that was part of the confusion): `REPLACEMENT` can be the empty string, resulting in the match being simply deleted.

Comment: Your fun facts are `seriously deep`, Another `statement`: In the `sahara` you can't go `snow bunting`. It is `so quiet one can hear a pin drop`.

Comment: `streetlight` and ilk work in `ed`, but not in `ex`/`vi` or `perl`. In Perl, you need whitespace after the `s` for an alphanumeric delemiter eg `perl  -wpe 's treetlight'`. These sorts of gotchas make letters a poor choice of delimiter.

Comment: If the inability to copy-paste `sed` code into Perl isn't a sufficient deal breaker, then I'd like to add that the sed command `streetlight` is also highly unreadable